# generate filename using variables

Tags: python

The following code is worked as expected. It saves excel sheets into different csv files each named as sheetname.csv The only change that I am trying is to add filename to the csv file. Something like data.xls.sheetname.csv

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import xlrd
import csv
from os import sys

def csv_from_excel(excel_file):
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(excel_file)
    all_worksheets = workbook.sheet_names()
    for worksheet_name in all_worksheets:
        worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(worksheet_name)
        your_csv_file = open(''.join([worksheet_name,'.csv']), 'wb')
        wr = csv.writer(your_csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

        for rownum in xrange(worksheet.nrows):
            wr.writerow([unicode(entry).encode("utf-8") for entry in worksheet.row_values(rownum)])
        your_csv_file.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    csv_from_excel(sys.argv[1])
```

The following change does not work as expected:

```
your_csv_file = open(''.join([excel_file,worksheet_name,'.csv']), 'wb')
```

Nor does the following is working:

```
your_csv_file = open(''.join([worksheet_name,'.csv']).join([excel_file]), 'wb')
```

Comment: What would a sample string look like for `worksheet_name`, `excel_file`, and `.csv` joined together?

Comment: `The following change does not work as expected:` is always so vague... What are you getting instead? An error? A wrong filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
your_csv_file = open(excel_file+''.join([worksheet_name,'.csv']), 'wb')
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you want a period between all the names, use `.` as the joiner:

```
'.'join([excel_file, worksheet_name, 'csv'])
```

What you are currently getting is data.xlssheetname.csv which is not what you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple format statement:

```
your_csv_filename = "{}.{}.{}".format(excel_file, worksheet_name, "cvs")
your_csv_file = open(your_csv_filename, 'wb')
```